# super() keyword with no parameter

Tags: java

```
package com.gpcoder.lambda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Product {
 int id;
 String name;
 float price;

    public Product(int id, String name, float price) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}

public class LambdaExpression6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Product(1, "Samsung A5", 17000f));
        list.add(new Product(3, "Iphone 6S", 65000f));
        list.add(new Product(2, "Sony Xperia", 25000f));
        list.add(new Product(4, "Nokia Lumia", 15000f));
        list.add(new Product(5, "Redmi4 ", 26000f));
        list.add(new Product(6, "Lenevo Vibe", 19000f));

        // using lambda to filter data
        Stream<Product> filtered_data = list.stream().filter(p -> p.price > 20000);

        // using lambda to iterate through collection
        filtered_data.forEach(product -> System.out.println(product.name + ": " + product.price));
    }
}
```

When I research Lambda expression I see this code with `super()` keywords. And I just know *The super keyword in Java is a reference variable which is used to refer immediate parent class object.* But in this code, the keyword `super()` with no parameter and no parents class. So why we have `super()` there.

Comment: You don't know that. It has another meaning: it provides the syntax for calling the base class constructor, in this case with no arguments. All classes except `java.lang.Object` have a base class.

Comment: It's superfluous.